# Merge two xml files and get one xml output using Saxon and xslt Stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I want to create transformation from multiple xml files to just one xml (Output.xml) using Saxon. The xml files will be generated by a specific merge.xslt file provided by my softwar (Vector CANoe). Suppose in one folder I have several files:

```
test_InitStartOP_report0001.xml
test_InitStartOP_report0002.xml
test_InitStartOP_report0003.xml
```

I want to output one xml file using this template from this stylesheet :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<!-- Merge list of XML reports to one single report  -->
<!-- merge.xslt                                      -->
<!-- Version 1.2                                     -->
<!-- (c) 2005  Vector Informatik GmbH, Stuttgart     -->

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <testmodule starttime="-" timestamp="-">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//testmodule" />
    <xsl:variable name="testmoduleresult">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="//testmodule/verdict/@result='fail'">fail</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>pass</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <verdict time="-" timestamp="-" endtime="-" endtimestamp="-" result='{$testmoduleresult}' />
    <title>Test Report</title>
    
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//testmodule[1]/engineer|//testmodule[1]/testsetup|//testmodule[1]/sut|//testmodule[1]/hardware" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//testmodule/miscinfo|//testmodule/extendedinfo" />
    
  </testmodule>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="testmodule">
  <testgroup>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="preparation|completion|testgroup|testcase|skipped|violation|moduledetails|externalref" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="title" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="description" />
    
    <!-- Write test module information -->
    <xsl:if test="testsetup">
      <xsl:for-each select="testsetup/xinfo|testsetup/info">
        <xsl:if test="local-name(.) != 'xinfo' or (name != 'Version' and name != 'Configuration' and name != 'Konfiguration' and name != 'Configuration Comment' and name != 'Konfigurationskommentar' and name != 'Windows Computer Name' and name != 'Windows Computer-Name' and not(starts-with(name, 'Nodelayer Module')) and not(starts-with(name, 'Nodelayer-Modul')))">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="tminfo" />
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if>
  </testgroup>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="info" mode="tminfo">
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xinfo" mode="tminfo">
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="preparation">
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="completion">
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="testgroup">
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="testcase">
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="skipped">
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="violation">
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="moduledetails">
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="miscinfo">
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="extendedinfo">
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="engineer">
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="hardware">
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="externalref">
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="testsetup">
  <testsetup>
    <xsl:for-each select="xinfo">
      <xsl:if test="name = 'Version' or name = 'Configuration' or name = 'Konfiguration' or name = 'Configuration Comment' or name = 'Konfigurationskommentar' or name = 'Windows Computer Name' or name = 'Windows Computer-Name' or starts-with(name, 'Nodelayer Module') or starts-with(name, 'Nodelayer-Modul')">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </testsetup>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sut">
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tried using Saxon in Cmd using this cmd line :

```
java -jar saxon-he-10.5.jar -xsl:merge.xslt -s:"test_InitStartOP_report0001.xml;test_InitStartOP_report0002.xml" -o:Output.xml
```

But it doesn't work, Anybody know how I can solve the problem?

Comment: So perhaps ask your software vendor how that XSLT code is supposed to be called or use with multiple documents. As for Saxon, I think the `-s` option needs to select a single document. In XSLT in general you have the `document` function to pull in other input documents, in XSLT 2 and 3 you additionally have the `doc` function and Saxon allows you to use `collection` and `uri-collection` to process a sequence of files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have not understood the requirement clearly, but I'm guessing that when you write

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//testmodule[1]/engineer|//testmodule[1]/testsetup|//testmodule[1]/sut|//testmodule[1]/hardware" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="//testmodule/miscinfo|//testmodule/extendedinfo" />
```

You actually want to select `testModule` elements in all the input documents. If that's the case, then the first thing is to have a variable `$allInputs` whose value is the set of input documents, and then change these expressions to, for example

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$allInputs//testModule/....."/>
```

The question then is how to bind the variable `$allInputs` to this set of documents. There are several ways to do this:

- use the collection() function
- use the document() function with a list of URIs
- pass all the documents in as a single stylesheet parameter

Since you're running from the command line, the simplest approach might be to change the command line to supply a stylesheet parameter containing the list of URIs, semicolon-separated:

```
inputFiles="test_InitStartOP_report0001.xml;test_InitStartOP_report0002.xml"
```

and then in the stylesheet you can do

```
<xsl:param name="inputFiles" as="xs:string" required="yes"/>
<xsl:variable name="allInputs" select="tokenize($inputFiles, ';')!document(.)" as="document-node()*"/>
```

Note that you then don't need a "principal input document" - drop the -s option on the command line, use -it instead, and change `<xsl:template match="/">` to `<xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">`.